# Semantic-ui Checkboxes and buttons check on PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, semantic-ui

`Semantic-ui` uses mainly `jquery` and `javascript`.
So when you use their jquery checkbox, and check it, it adds '`checked`' class to it.

The problem is, I want to use PHP `isset()` function, to know if the checkbox is checked or not, but because the checkbox itself isn't checked, I cant.

How can I identify a checked `Semantic-ui` checkbox on `PHP`?
Thank you.

Comment: is the checkbox a input type checkbox?

Comment: You answered your question in the opening, check for class name 'checked' instead of checking for a tickbox being checked.  example: $('#test').hasClass('checked')

Comment: @krisph The thing is, I want to use PHP to identify, not JQuery. you got me?

Comment: Ok, just looked at the documentation briefly and you should be able to check the textbox yourself using the 'onChange' event...

Comment: @krisph used callbacks, onChecked & onUnchecked. Thank tou for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Form:**

```
<form class="ui form" action="your_action.php" method="post">
   <div class="field">
    <label>First Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
   </div>    
  <div class="field">
   <div class="ui checkbox">
     <input name='check' type="checkbox" tabindex="0" class="hidden">
    <label>I agree to the Terms and Conditions</label>
   </div>
 </div>
  <button name='action' value="submit" class="ui button" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**your_action.php**

simply check the checkbox as :

```
if ($_REQUEST['action'] == 'submit') {
    if(isset($_REQUEST['check']) and $_REQUEST['check'] == 'on') {
      //do you stuff
    }
```

**If you want to check within javascript use checkbox's "is checked" behaviour**

```
$('.ui.checkbox').checkbox(<i>behavior</i>, argumentOne, argumentTwo...);
```

Comment: Used is checked and is unchecked to add the attr to the checkbox itself. Thank you very much!